# ASP.NET MVC 5 : pass connection string from service method and not web.config

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I have seen several SO posts of how to dynamically pass a connection string but none seem to work for me.

I have an ASP.NET MVC 5 application that was created to use ASP.NET Identity (during project creation in VS2019).

Also, I have a service method that accepts a string and returns a connection string of type string.

```
public string GetConStringFromDomain(string domain)
{
     return 'my constring from api'; 
}
```

My `ApplicationDbContext` class looks like this

```
public ApplicationDbContext() : base("DefaultConnection")
{
}

public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
{
    return new ApplicationDbContext();
}
```

Whenever I have to access this class, `ApplicationDbContext` from a controller, I am sure I can pass a connection string by adding another constructor that takes an argument of type string to my `ApplicationDbContext` class.

My question comes to the User login under the `AccountController`.

This controller initializes two properties:

```
 public ApplicationSignInManager SignInManager
 {
        get
        {
            return _signInManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationSignInManager>();
        }
        private set
        {
            _signInManager = value;
        }
}

public ApplicationUserManager UserManager
{
        get
        {
            return _userManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
        }
        private set
        {
            _userManager = value;
        }
}
```

How can I pass my connection string dynamically to these implementations?

Answer (score 0):

```
public ApplicationDbContext() : base(SetConnectionString())
{
}

public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
{
    return new ApplicationDbContext();
}

private static SetConnectionString(){ //get from appsettings, db or... }
```

Comment: My service is an Async function which takes in one argument of type string. This service queries a different db and the argument, subdomain, is obtained during login. How can I achieve that.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) will help people understand the reasons for your code suggestion.